# Openpyxl To Unfilter Excel Workbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am learning python and am using the library `openpyxl` and i see an infinite number of examples on how to do custom sorting and custom filtering.  The one thing I am not seeing is how to unfilter a worksheet that is already filtered.

Using this library, how would I unfilter the worksheet?